# How to deserialize null type JSON fields with Jackson

Tags: java, json, null, jackson, deserialization

I'm developing a PATCH API. If the fields are sent as `JSON` `null` value I need to save them as `null`. However I can't distinguish if they're sent as `null` or never sent.

```
{
      "max_amount": null
}
```

```java
Double maxAmount;
```

I have `Double`, `Integer`, `Date` etc. fields. I can deserialize them to `Double.NAN`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` when they're really sent as `null` to understand if they're sent as `null`. But Deserializers don't work when the field is `null`. Of course it's an option to send "-1" or an impossible value to define `null` but I didn't like this approach. I will have to agree with the clients for all types. What's the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this you should define `POJO` class with properties set to predefined `undefined like` data. For example, for `Integer` property if negative numbers are not allowed from business point of view, it could be `-1`. Then, when `JSON` is deserialised to `POJO` properties set to `null` override default values and you will know it was sent. There should be 3 options:

1. Regular value in `JSON` - properly deserialised to a value in `POJO`
2. `null` value in `JSON` - deserialised to `null` in `POJO`
3. Not available pair `key-value` - default value in `POJO` is not overridden.

Below example uses `Jackson` in version `2.9.9`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        String[] jsons = {
                "{\"number\":1,\"date\":\"2019-01-01T22:23:11\",\"max_amount\":4.9}",
                "{\"number\":null,\"date\":null,\"max_amount\":null}",
                "{}",
                "{\"number\":1}",
                "{\"date\":\"2019-01-01T22:23:11\"}",
                "{\"max_amount\":4.9}",
                "{\"number\":1,\"date\":null,\"max_amount\":null}"
        };
        for (String json : jsons) {
            System.out.println(json + " => " + mapper.readValue(json, Pojo.class));
        }
    }
}

class Pojo {

    private static final LocalDateTime NULL_DATE = LocalDateTime.of(1900, 1, 1, 12, 13);

    @JsonProperty("max_amount")
    private Double maxAmount = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    private Integer number = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDateTime date = NULL_DATE;

    public Double getMaxAmount() {
        return maxAmount;
    }

    public void setMaxAmount(Double maxAmount) {
        this.maxAmount = maxAmount;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "number=" + number +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", maxAmount=" + maxAmount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"number":1,"date":"2019-01-01T22:23:11","max_amount":4.9} => {number=1, date=2019-01-01T22:23:11, maxAmount=4.9}
{"number":null,"date":null,"max_amount":null} => {number=null, date=null, maxAmount=null}
{} => {number=-2147483648, date=1900-01-01T12:13, maxAmount=4.9E-324}
{"number":1} => {number=1, date=1900-01-01T12:13, maxAmount=4.9E-324}
{"date":"2019-01-01T22:23:11"} => {number=-2147483648, date=2019-01-01T22:23:11, maxAmount=4.9E-324}
{"max_amount":4.9} => {number=-2147483648, date=1900-01-01T12:13, maxAmount=4.9}
{"number":1,"date":null,"max_amount":null} => {number=1, date=null, maxAmount=null}
```

Of course, you should pick default values in the way it will minimise possibility of collision that client by accident send value treated as `undefined` by your `API`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and effort. However we find a better solution to get rid of default values. We defined a isMaxAmountSet boolean value and set it true at the setter of maxAmount. So, we can distinguish if this value is sent or not at request body.