# Deserialize a property which is having null as a value using object mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I have one JSON string which is already serialized. While serializing from source, null property values were not ignored. Hence serialized output of the object is something like:

```
"person": {
  "name": "foo",
  "surname": null
}
```

Now if I Deserialize above using object mapper in Java, it throws an exception, pointing to value not available. Is there any way object mapper can deserialize "surname" back to "null"? Can I configure object mapper to not fail under such scenarios?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911836/how-to-deserialize-null-type-json-fields-with-jackson

Comment: Please, add a stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, JsonProcessingException {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name = "Hades";
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonWithNull = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
            System.out.println("Before :: "+jsonWithNull);
            
            mapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); // U cant use the same object create a new one
            String jsonWithOutNull = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
            System.out.println("After :: "+jsonWithOutNull);
            
            System.out.println("While deserializing");
            

            //********************
            //This is how u should read a null string into ur Java class
            Person p = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNull, Person.class);//user null string with Mapper
            System.out.println(p);
            
        }
    
    
    class Person{
        public String name;
        public String surName;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + ", surName=" + surName + "]";
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Before :: {"name":"Hades","surName":null}
After :: {"name":"Hades"}

While deserializing
Person [name=Hades, surName=null]
```

Comment: Hi @Hades, one issue with this approach is I don't have control over the source, in your case "map". I'm getting the string with nulls from external source